# Getting array of struct from another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, contract

I have 2 contracts.

```
contract Contract1{
  struct Data {
      uint data1;
      string data2;
  }
  Data [] newData;
}
```

Let's assume that I have datas in newData

```
import "./Contract1.sol";
contract Contract2{
  Data storage newOne = newData[0];
}
```

I want to reach array of struct which is in Contract1 as above.
How can I access to Contract1 from Contract2?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend a contract with the `is` keyword.

Child contracts (in your case `Contract2`) can access all [non-private](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) parent (in your case `Contract1`) properties.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "./Contract1.sol";

contract Contract2 is Contract1 {
    function foo() external {
        Data storage newOne = newData[0];
        // newOne.data1 = 1;
        // newOne.data2 = 'hello';
    }
}
```

---

Edit: Mind that `newData[0]` is trying to access index `0` of the array, but when the contract is deployed, the array is empty (does not have index 0). You can create the first item (with index 0 and dummy data) by executing this function:

```
function add() external {
    newData.push(Data(1, 'a'));
}
```

Comment: I got an type error.
Contract "Contract2" should be marked as abstact.

Comment: @almi That's unrelated to your original question and to the solution. The "should be marked as abstract" error shows up when your contract has a function definition without implementation, e.g. `function foo() external;` (mind the semicolon at the end and no function body).